# value of localStorage in crosswalk lost after restart app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk

I use ionic to create my app.
Because perfomance problem in android device so i have to integrate app with crosswalk,.
My app use localStorage to store many setting info , use it like local **variables**

My problem is when use crosswalk, each time i restart the app, variable store in localStorage is lost!

After do alot of solution, i try:

- https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage --> This solution can storage persistent value & variables, but it use promise to get the value, isn't like localStorage way ( just set value for variables, use it synchronize ). So this not my goal, use as localStorage
- https://github.com/munisense/cordova-plugin-local-storage-retrieval.git --> A Cordova plugin to be used with alternate browsers to retrieve localstorage from default system browsers --> But when i use this plugin, problem still occur

Some version of framework used in my project:

- ionic 1.7.14
- cordova 5.4.1
- crosswalk 18+

Please help me solve this!

Comment: If you are testing on a device, ensure that you have enough device memory

Comment: @Gandhi i was testing on both simulator & device , have the same result. Didn't you get lost data when use crosswalk ?

Comment: I cant comment on that as i dont have hands on experience on crosswalk. But there was a similar issue in old version of crosswalk as well. Check this out - https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-4260 Hope it has not resurfaced again.

Comment: thanks for your investigating , it seem problem occur again!. i bum out of my head but still stuck at this :(.

Comment: Try reporting to official crosswalk jira. It may be genuine issue